# firebase.auth().SignInWithPhoneNumber is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

```
window.onload=function(){
  render();
};

function render(){
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');

  recaptchaVerifier.render().then(widgetId => {
  window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
})
}

function phoneAuth(){
  var number=document.getElementById('number').value;
  firebase.auth().SignInWithPhoneNumber(number,window.recaptchaVerifier).then(function(confirmationResult){
    //const sentCodeId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
    //signInWithPhoneButton.addEventListener('click', () => signInWithPhone(sentCodeId));
    window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    coderesult=confirmationResult;
    console.log(coderesult);
    alert("Message sent");
  }).catch(function(error){
    alert(error.message);
  });
}

function codeverify(){
  var code= document.getElementById('verificationCode').value
  coderesult.confirm(code).then(function(result){
    alert("Successfully register");
    var user=result.user;
    console.log(user);
  }).catch(function(error){
    alert(error.message);
  });
}
```

```
 <h1>Enter number</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id ="number" placeholder="+49**********">
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
      <button type="button" onclick="phoneAuth();">SendCode</button>
    </form><br>
    <h1>Enter Code</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id ="verificationCode" placeholder="Enter verification Code">
      <button type="button" onclick="codeverify();">Verify Code</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-analytics.js"></script>-->
    
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "-",
        authDomain: "-",
        databaseURL: "-",
        projectId: "-",
        storageBucket: "-",
        messagingSenderId: "-",
        appId: "-",
        measurementId: "-"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      //firebase.analytics();
    
      // make auth and firestore references
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      const db = firebase.firestore();
    
      // update firestore settings
      //db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
    </script>
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script> -->
      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Hello everyone! I want to use the Firebase-Phone-Authentication but it's not working, here my code.
Everytime I want to use it there is an error in the console "firebase.auth().SignInWithPhoneNumber is not a function".I have watched some videos on Youtube and also tried some code from the internet but nothing works. I'm thankful for every Help:)!

Comment: `SignInWithPhoneNumber` should be `signInWithPhoneNumber`. JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Always check the docs first: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone